# redirect to another page if user has registered successfully

Tags: redirect, user-registration

I am very new to wordpress and I don't know anything yet.
I have a custom registration page which works well, but after registration doesn't do any thing and user has to manually go to his profile via menu on top of the page!
I want to automatically redirect to his profile page after registration.
how can i do that?

thank you

```
    <h3>ثبت نام</h3>


<form name="learn-press-register" action="" method="post">


    <ul class="form-fields">
                        <li class="form-field">
                <div class="rwmb-field rwmb-text-wrapper "><div class="rwmb-field rwmb-text-wrapper ">
                <label for="reg_username">نام کاربری</label>

            </div><div class="rwmb-field rwmb-text-wrapper "><input name="reg_username" class="rwmb-field rwmb-text-wrapper " id="reg_username" required="" type="text" size="30" placeholder="نام کاربری"></div><input class="rwmb-field rwmb-text-wrapper " type="hidden" value="reg_username"><div class="rwmb-field rwmb-text-wrapper "></div></div>                </li>
                        <li class="form-field">
                <div class="rwmb-field rwmb-email-wrapper "><div class="rwmb-field rwmb-email-wrapper ">
                <label for="reg_email">ایمیل</label>

            </div><div class="rwmb-field rwmb-email-wrapper "><input name="reg_email" class="rwmb-field rwmb-email-wrapper " id="reg_email" required="" type="email" size="30" placeholder="ایمیل"></div><input class="rwmb-field rwmb-email-wrapper " type="hidden" value="reg_email"><div class="rwmb-field rwmb-email-wrapper "></div></div>                </li>
                        <li class="form-field">
                <div class="rwmb-field rwmb-password-wrapper "><div class="rwmb-field rwmb-password-wrapper ">
                <label for="reg_password">کلمه عبور</label>

            </div><div class="rwmb-field rwmb-password-wrapper "><input name="reg_password" class="rwmb-field rwmb-password-wrapper " id="reg_password" required="" type="password" size="30" placeholder="کلمه عبور"><p class="description" id="reg_password-description">رمز عبور باید حداقل 12 حرف باشد سمبلهای مقابل استفاده کنید ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; )</p></div><input class="rwmb-field rwmb-password-wrapper " type="hidden" value="reg_password"><div class="rwmb-field rwmb-password-wrapper "></div></div>                </li>
                </ul>


    <p>
        <input name="learn-press-register-nonce" id="learn-press-register-nonce" type="hidden" value="6c324d4ef8"><input name="_wp_http_referer" type="hidden" value="/%D9%BE%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%81%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%84-%D9%85%D9%86/">     
   <button type="submit">ثبت نام</button>

    </p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `registration_redirect` hook, add this into your theme's `functions.php`

```
function wpse_registration_redirect() {
    return home_url( '/page' );
}

add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'wpse_registration_redirect' );
```

Comment: Note that add_filter are great ways to modify how WP works. As a person new to WP, and if you are interested in modifying how things work in WP, start here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/ . As to which filter to look at, you can usually get a hint by looking at the code that runs a particular page. Another place to learn about filters: https://docs.presscustomizr.com/article/26-wordpress-actions-filters-and-hooks-a-guide-for-non-developers . Many choices if you ask the googles.

Comment: Indeed Rick, cool resource.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know why  non of these filters do not work out!

Comment: Deactivate all the plugins and check again, if it works, it is a plugin that is blocking it by mistake, if you find the plugin and it's really important and cannot be replace it, show us the code of your custom registration page so we can find a work around.

Comment: Depends on where you are putting your code. It needs to be in functions.php file. Best to put it in a Child Theme, as putting it in the current theme's folder will cause your changes to go away on a theme update. So: use a Child Theme, put your function in the function.php in your Child Theme folder, then activate the Child Theme. If you are not using a Child Theme, you should: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes .  You could also put it in your own plugin, but that's a bit more advanced. For leaning: look in the Codex for how templates work, and more. Lots of good info there to help.

Comment: I have added it to functions.php but I think the plugin "learnpress" which I'm using, blocks it. How can I add it to my plugin?

Comment: By the way, sir @Castiblanco; this is my code in custom registration, I simply copied from the lp-profile page in plugin learnpress and it registers users but I don't know how to redirect to their own profile.

Comment: sir @RickHellewell , If my plugin blocks me to redirect, Child_theme will help?

Comment: No, it won't, the childtheme helps you to not lost changes after an update.

Comment: To override any action in the plugin, you could adjust the priority of your add_filter to fire before or after the plugin does. Experiment with different values. Or, you could look at the plugin's code to see what filter they are using, then use the same filter with a later priority in your code.